# How to get the Jenkins build number in Android?

Tags: java, android

How do I get Jenkins build number in Android java file/code because the jenkins will generate a build number after every build and the Android application should capture the jenkins build number dynamically from jenkins.

**I have done the same thing in Build.gradle file**

```
def BUILD_NUMBER = System.getenv("BUILD_NUMBER") ? System.getenv("BUILD_NUMBER") : "0"
def PversCode = "90$BUILD_NUMBER"
print ("VersionCode is....." + "90$BUILD_NUMBER")
versionCode PversCode as Integer
def PversName = "9.0.$BUILD_NUMBER"
versionName PversName as String
print ("VersionName is....." + "9.0.$BUILD_NUMBER")
```

But how I do it using java code?

Comment: Do you want to use this number in android project or you just want to read it?

Comment: I want to get the build number from jenkins and use/assign it in in my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it a maven project?

Jenkins sets some environment variables you can read: 
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project

Additionally, you can try something like that: 
`mvn clean install -Dbuild.number=${BUILD_NUMBER}`. Where build.number is your property in your pom. Of course, you can write this build number afterwards to you manifest and access it from java code.

Comment: It is an android project, so i want to get the jenkin build number from the jenkin to my android application.

Comment: If you build your Android application with maven, you can get the build number within you pom and write it to the manifest file. The application can read this file.

If you want to use gradle, in gradle it is possible to read the environment variable BUILD_NUMBER, too. Something like this: ext.buildNumber = System.getenv("BUILD_NUMBER") ?: "dev"

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the BuildNumber from Jenkins to the BuildConfig.java
In you app's build.gradle:

```
android {
...
    defaultConfig {
        buildConfigField "long", "BUILD_NUMBER", "$BUILD_NUMBER"
        ....
    }
}
```

In your project's build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext{
        BUILD_NUMBER = 7
    }
    ....
}
```

Finally, when you trigger the build you can do following in jenkins:

`gradlew assembleDebup -PBUILD_NUMBER=$BUILD_NUMBER`

Whenever you want to access this value in your code, you can do following:

`long jenkinsBuildNumber = BuildConfig.BUILD_NUMBER;`

Comment: The chromium android i use doesn't have Build.gradle instead it has Build.gn File.